# How to exclude everything that is not in the include - Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If I have a trigger that looks like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - abc/def/*
```

Is everything that is NOT in that path automatically excluded? If not, how can I exclude everything that is not in that path `abc/def/*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your YAML trigger file, it should be excluded everything that is not in the include path. It is equivalent to exclude *.

You can specify file paths to include or exclude in the YAML file.

When you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on. You can't trigger a pipeline with only a path filter; you must also have a branch filter, and the changed files that match the path filter must be from a branch that matches the branch filter.

For more information, you could refer to [Paths in YAML Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths).